# Подсчет количества дней

Tags: php, mysql

После регистрации пользователю записывается в базу данных (поле `date_reg` тип `DATE`) дата регистрации, вот как подсчитать и вывести количество дней с момента регистрации пользователя, например:
Вася Иванов с нами уже 20 дней 4 месяца 2 года!

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), `date_reg`);
```

Получите количество дней. Что дальше делать - думаю, обьяснять не надо

Comment: офигенно, это работает только если формат DATE? Если обычный varchar с UNIX таймом, то не сработает, да?

Comment: varchar с unixtime ?? сеньор знатный извращенец.

Comment: @mctrane, работает :)
если формат юникс, тогда (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - `your_unix_time`) - результат в секундах, поделить его на (60x60x24) - и снова то же количество дней.

Более элегантное решение - TIMESTAMPDIFF();

P.S. Согласен с @eicto, синьйор знает толк в изврашениях :) Используйте int(10)

Comment: Ну а что такого, для меня UNIX тайм удобен тем, что из него можно дату любого вида сделать, тип поля не важен. Многие CMSки так делают. ЭТо не повод называть меня извращенцем.

Answer (score 0):

Переводи дату в UNIX time ([mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)):

```
$data_reg = explode('-', $row['data_reg']);
$t_reg = mktime(0,0,0,$data_reg[1],$data_reg[2],$data_reg[0]);
$t = time();
$t_count = $t-$t_reg;
$count_days = $t_count/86400; //Получаем кол-во дней
if($count_days>=365){
$count_years = floor($count_days/365);  //Кол-во лет
$count_days = $count_days-$count_years*365;
}
if($count_days>=30){
$count_mons = floor($count_days/30); //Кол-во месяцев
$count_days = $count_days-$count_mons*30;
}
```

Вот можно так, дорабатывай как тебе надо :) Например, чтобы не все месяца считало бы по 30 дней.